# In member function 'virtual void ... TestBody()'

Tags: c++, googletest

edit*: The full error message: test_huffman.cpp: In member function 'virtual void HuffmanTest_Test_Test::TestBody()'

I'm trying to write a google test for some cpp code. I'm getting an error and I'm not sure how to fix it. This is the error: test_huffman.cpp: In member function 'virtual void HuffmanTest_Test_Test::TestBody()'. The only answer I found online is that I need an argument list? Not sure where to go from here. The huffman.h/.cpp are probably not necessary but figured I'd share them (no I didn't write them they are open source);

Here is the code that I get the error when I compile (w/ gcc):

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "huffman.h"


TEST(HuffmanTest, Test)
{
    char* words[3];
    words[0] = "one\0";
    words[1] = "two\0";
    words[2] = "three\0";
    int frequencies[UniqueSymbols] = {0};
    for(int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
    {
        const char* ptr = words[i];
        while (*ptr != '\0')
            ++frequencies[*ptr++];
    }

    INode* root = BuildTree(frequencies);
    HuffCodeMap codes;
    GenerateCodes(root, HuffCode(), codes);
    delete root;
    EXPECT_FALSE(codes.empty());

}
```

Huffman.h (open source):

```
#ifndef huffman_h_INCLUDED
#define huffman_h_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <map>
#include <climits> // for CHAR_BIT
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

const int UniqueSymbols = 1 << CHAR_BIT;

typedef std::vector<bool> HuffCode;
typedef std::map<char, HuffCode> HuffCodeMap;

class INode
{
public:
    const int f;

    virtual ~INode();

protected:
    INode(int f);
};

class InternalNode : public INode
{
public:
    INode *const left;
    INode *const right;

    InternalNode(INode* c0, INode* c1);
    ~InternalNode();
};

class LeafNode : public INode
{
public:
    const char c;

    LeafNode(int f, char c);
};

struct NodeCmp
{
  bool operator()(const INode* lhs, const INode* rhs) const;
};

INode* BuildTree(const int (&frequencies)[UniqueSymbols]);
void GenerateCodes(const INode* node, const HuffCode& prefix, HuffCodeMap& outCodes);

#endif // huffman_h_INCLUDED
```

huffman.cpp (open source):

```
#include "huffman.h"

INode :: ~INode()
{
}

INode :: INode(int f)
  : f(f)
{
}

InternalNode :: InternalNode(INode* c0, INode* c1)
  : INode(c0->f + c1->f), left(c0), right(c1)
{
}

InternalNode :: ~InternalNode()
{
  delete left;
  delete right;
}

LeafNode :: LeafNode(int f, char c)
  : INode(f), c(c)
{
}

bool NodeCmp :: operator()(const INode* lhs, const INode* rhs) const { return lhs->f > rhs->f; }

INode* BuildTree(const int (&frequencies)[UniqueSymbols])
{
    std::priority_queue<INode*, std::vector<INode*>, NodeCmp> trees;

    for (int i = 0; i < UniqueSymbols; ++i)
    {
        if(frequencies[i] != 0)
            trees.push(new LeafNode(frequencies[i], (char)i));
    }
    while (trees.size() > 1)
    {
        INode* childR = trees.top();
        trees.pop();

        INode* childL = trees.top();
        trees.pop();

        INode* parent = new InternalNode(childR, childL);
        trees.push(parent);
    }
    return trees.top();
}

void GenerateCodes(const INode* node, const HuffCode& prefix, HuffCodeMap& outCodes)
{
    if (const LeafNode* lf = dynamic_cast<const LeafNode*>(node))
    {
        outCodes[lf->c] = prefix;
    }
    else if (const InternalNode* in = dynamic_cast<const InternalNode*>(node))
    {
        HuffCode leftPrefix = prefix;
        leftPrefix.push_back(false);
        GenerateCodes(in->left, leftPrefix, outCodes);

        HuffCode rightPrefix = prefix;
        rightPrefix.push_back(true);
        GenerateCodes(in->right, rightPrefix, outCodes);
    }
}
```

Comment: is your error message complete?

Comment: It would not be a frightfully bad idea to quote the error message, and perhaps indicate the location.

Comment: You've still not posted the full error message.